# Lookup in a multidimensional hash

Tags: perl, hashtable, lookup, perl-data-structures

I have this data structure (a multidimensional hash table):

```
$VAR1 = {
      'cat' => {
               "félin" => '0.500000',
               'chat' => '0.600000'
             },
      'rabbit' => {
                  'lapin' => '0.600000'
                },
      'canteen' => {
                   "ménagère" => '0.400000',
                   'cantine' => '0.600000'
                 }
       };
```

My goal is to read a tokenized text, and for each word I need to find the translation(s). For my tokens, I read my text and I create an array like that:

```
##store each word to translate in a table
while(my $text_to_translate = <TEXTTOTRANSLATE>)
{       
    my @temp = split(/ /, $text_to_translate);
    push(@tokens, @temp);               
}
```

My problem is to find the best way (and the fastest) to lookup into the bidimensional hash table and print the possible translation(s) like that:

> I love my cat[chat;félin] and my rabbit[lapin].

For now, I had create this loop but It didn't work well, and I think it is not the best way:

```
foreach my $source (sort keys %hash) {
    foreach my $target (keys %{ $hash{$source} }) {
            my $val = $source;
                ##loop into each tokens             
                foreach (@tokens) { 
                    my $actualWord = $_; 

                    if($val eq $actualWord){
                        print $actualWord."==>".$target."\n";
                    } 
                    else{
                            print $actualWord."\n";
                        next;
                    }                                   
                }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would do :

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict; use warnings;

my $hash = {
      'cat' => {
               "félin" => '0.500000',
               'chat' => '0.600000'
             },
      'rabbit' => {
                  'lapin' => '0.600000'
                },
      'canteen' => {
                   "ménagère" => '0.400000',
                   'cantine' => '0.600000'
                 }
       };

my $text = "I love my cat and my rabbit canteen !\n";

foreach my $word (split /\s/, $text) {
    print $word;
    exists $hash->{$word}
        and print "[" . join(";", keys %{ $hash->{$word} }) . "]";
    print " ";
}

print "\n";
```

Output:

```
I love my cat[chat;félin] and my rabbit[lapin] canteen[cantine;ménagère] !
```

Comment: See http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html and http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html